# Multi submenu not working properly in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Created a menu with multi submenu but right now the submenu and submultimenu is not hiding properly can any one help on this. When i mouseover on One list showing submenu but in the same way when i mouseout on that one or submultimenu this has to hide.

right now my logic is need to create submulti menus

[Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/RHVDT/19/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I muddled around with it a bit, from what i have done in the past this is what i came up with

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/RHVDT/31/

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using plugins, consider jdMenu or a similar jQuery plugin: http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/

If not, adjust your code to hide `.submenu2` when mousing out of the associated `.submenu`:

```
$('.submenu').mouseout(function () {
  $('.submenu2').hide(); 
  $('.submenu').hide(); 
});
```

If you do that, also adjust your CSS so the user can navigate to `.submenu2` without triggering a `mouseout` event on `.submenu`, which would hide the `.submenu2` they're trying to navigate to.

Minor edits to your fiddle (added `$('.submenu2').hide()` and adjusted the CSS for `.submenu2`) can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/RHVDT/21/